# gdb throws "No source file named handleChars.cpp" after break command despite including -g flag

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, gdb

When I try `(gdb) break handleChars.cpp:9` I get a `No source file named handleChars.cpp` error despite including that source file and the -g flag in my Makefile.

Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -g
SOURCES= tests.cpp line.cpp handleChars.cpp print.cpp moveCursor.cpp
DEPS= sim.h 
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=exec 

all: $(EXECUTABLE)
    @echo Make has finished
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $*.cpp
```

Edit: even after correcting the spelling of `CFLAGS`, the error remains.

Comment: `CFlags` ≠ `CFLAGS`

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: @Patrick After fixing your `Makefile`, you need to `rm *.o; make` again. Pay attention to presence of `-g` on compile command line. If this still doesn't work, _show_ the build output in your question.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce.  Worked on my machine.